# How to resize twitter bootstrap popover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am using bootstrap in my mvc project. I have an issue with bootstrap popover widget. I have created a custom knockout binding for popover widget, here the code :

[Check fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfkLM/4/)

```
 ko.bindingHandlers.popover = {
        init: function (element, valuesAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valuesAccessor() || {});

            options.html = true;

            options.content = '<small class="text-info">' + 'Variable text goes here.Variable text goes here.Variable text goes here.Variable text goes here.Variable text goes here. ' + '</small>';

            $(element).popover(options);
        },
        update: function (element, valuesAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var extraOptions = allBindingsAccessor().popoverOptions;

            $(element).popover(extraOptions.observable() ? "show" : "hide");
            $(element).siblings('.popover').css({ width: '150px' });

            //IF YOU UN-COMMENT BELOW 2 LINES THAN EVERY THINGS WORKS FINE

            //if(extraOptions.observable())
                //$(element).popover('show');
        }
    };

    function vm() {
        var self = this;

        self.isVisible = ko.observable(false);

        self.open = function () {
            self.isVisible(!self.isVisible());
        };
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

I want to initialize popover on any element with variable text message and with variable size. Every thing goes ok but when i change the default width of the popover than on first time when it open its position is not correct *(please check the behavior in fiddle)*.

There was some line of code in the fiddle which if you uncomment than this issue solve. But i feel it is a hacky approach, i want some better way to handle if there is any ?

Answer (score 11):

Here's a sample initialization that I use.

```
    $(".property-price")
    .popover({ 
            trigger: "hover", 
            placement: 'bottom',
            toggle : "popover",
            content : "The from price is calculated ba....the dates selected.",
            title: "How is the from price calculated?",
            container: 'body',
            template: '<div class="popover popover-medium"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>',
        });
```

As you can see, it uses a custom template. The template uses a custom popover-medium class.

I then have a CSS selector

```
.popover-medium {
    max-width: 350px;
}
```

You could also just set a style on the template class if you wanted.

Comment: PS. All the answers I found for this tried to overcomplicate this easy task so much. This is the easiest non-hacky solution.

Answer (score 2):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bfkLM/8/)**

Try this I have edited your code

```
ko.bindingHandlers.popover = {
        init: function (element, valuesAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valuesAccessor() || {});



            options.html = true;

            options.content = '<small class="text-info">' + 'Variable text goes here.Variable text goes here.Variable text goes here.Variable text goes here.Variable text goes here. ' + '</small>';

            $(element).popover(options);


        },
        update: function (element, valuesAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var extraOptions = allBindingsAccessor().popoverOptions;

            $(element).popover(extraOptions.observable() ? "show" : "hide");


            //IF YOU UN-COMMENT BELOW 2 LINES THAN EVERY THINGS WORKS FINE

            //if(extraOptions.observable())
                //$(element).popover('show');
        }
    };

    function vm() {
        var self = this;

        self.isVisible = ko.observable(false);

        self.open = function () {
            self.isVisible(!self.isVisible());
        };
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

just add this css

```
.popover {
    max-width: 150px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Hope this helps
Thank you

Comment: The width of popover is not 150 inn your demo, it is default

Comment: @user1740381 now its working I have edited the code.Check this out

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the width after initializing the popover. The calculated top left position of the popover stays in place, but the width gets smaller. This causes the height to get greater.

You'll need to reorder your events so that width is applied before popover is initialized.

Comment: I did that but popover div is not present before initializing so changes take no effect

Comment: I'm trying to offer a demo, but I'm not sure what you're basing your width adjustment on. It seems arbitrary. Why not just set the width with CSS?